# How can I "nest" objects with OpenRDF Alibaba with assigned resource IRIs?

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, sesame, linked-data, openrdf

I am trying out [OpenRDF Alibaba](https://bitbucket.org/openrdf/alibaba) (associated with [Sesame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sesame_%28framework%29)) as a tool to map Java objects to RDF triples and back again.  Currently, I'm looking at how it handles object graphs.

I have two objects, Inner and Outer.  Outer has a reference to Inner.  When I persist an Outer-instance, it seems that the Inner-instance is aways represented as b-node, even if I've persisted the Inner-instance with an assigned IRI previously.

What do I have to do to be able to successfully assign the Inner-instance's IRI myself, instead of getting b-nodes created?

Extra credit question: how can I make the resource IRI a property on the Java object, rather than having it be parallel to but disconnected from the object it identifies?

---

**Code:**

Inner:

```java
package alibabaeval.domain;

import org.openrdf.annotations.Iri;

@Iri("http://example.com/innerType")
public class Inner {

    @Iri("http://example.com/innerType/data")
    private String data;

    public Inner(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }


    // if this is missing, an unhelpful ClassCastException will be thrown on retrieval
    public Inner() {
    }

    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

Outer:

```java
package alibabaeval.domain;

import org.openrdf.annotations.Iri;

@Iri("http://example.com/outerType")
public class Outer {

    @Iri("http://example.com/outerType/data")
    private String outerData;

    @Iri("http://example.com/outerType/innerObject")
    private Inner innerObject;

    public Outer(String outerData) {
        this.outerData = outerData;
    }

    // if this is missing, an unhelpful ClassCastException will be thrown on retrieval
    public Outer() {
    }

    public String getOuterData() {
        return outerData;
    }

    public void setOuterData(String outerData) {
        this.outerData = outerData;
    }

    public Inner getInnerObject() {
        return innerObject;
    }

    public void setInnerObject(Inner innerObject) {
        this.innerObject = innerObject;
    }
}
```

Test Program:

```java
package alibabaeval;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.openrdf.model.URI;
import org.openrdf.model.ValueFactory;
import org.openrdf.query.QueryLanguage;
import org.openrdf.repository.Repository;
import org.openrdf.repository.object.ObjectConnection;
import org.openrdf.repository.object.ObjectRepository;
import org.openrdf.repository.object.config.ObjectRepositoryFactory;
import org.openrdf.repository.sail.SailRepository;
import org.openrdf.rio.RDFFormat;
import org.openrdf.rio.RDFWriter;
import org.openrdf.rio.Rio;
import org.openrdf.sail.memory.MemoryStore;

import alibabaeval.domain.Inner;
import alibabaeval.domain.Outer;

public class AlibabaEval {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Repository store = new SailRepository(new MemoryStore());
        store.initialize();

        // wrap in an object repository
        ObjectRepositoryFactory factory = new ObjectRepositoryFactory();
        ObjectRepository repository = factory.createRepository(store);

        // add a stuff to the repository
        ObjectConnection con = repository.getConnection();
        ValueFactory vf = con.getValueFactory();

        Inner inner = new Inner("some inner data");
        URI innerId = vf.createURI("http://example.com/inners/inner1");
        con.addObject(innerId, inner);

        URI outerId = vf.createURI("http://example.com/outers/outer1");
        Outer outer = new Outer("some outer data");
        outer.setInnerObject(inner);
        con.addObject(outerId, outer);

        // look at the triples that were created
        System.out.println("\n\n\nGenerated triples:");
        RDFWriter writer = Rio.createWriter(RDFFormat.NTRIPLES, System.out);
        con.prepareGraphQuery(QueryLanguage.SPARQL, "CONSTRUCT { ?s ?p ?o } WHERE {?s ?p ?o }").evaluate(writer);

        // close everything down
        con.close();
        repository.shutDown();
    }
}
```

---

**Output:**

I created only two object instances, and persisted them both separately.  Alibaba seemed to ignore that, and created a second copy of the Inner-instance as a b-node for the reference from the Outer-instance.

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/me/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/slf4j-jdk14/1.7.7/25d160723ea37a6cb84e87cd70773ff02997e857/slf4j-jdk14-1.7.7.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/me/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.12/485f77901840cf4e8bf852f2abb9b723eb8ec29/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.12.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.JDK14LoggerFactory]
Jan 08, 2016 6:00:21 PM org.openrdf.repository.object.managers.helpers.Scanner scan
INFO: Scanning C:\workspace\AlibabaTest\bin for concepts
Jan 08, 2016 6:00:22 PM org.openrdf.repository.object.ObjectRepository compileSchema
INFO: Compiling schema
Jan 08, 2016 6:00:22 PM org.openrdf.repository.object.composition.ClassResolver setBaseClassRoles
WARNING: Concept will only be mergable: class alibabaeval.domain.Inner
Jan 08, 2016 6:00:22 PM org.openrdf.repository.object.composition.ClassResolver setBaseClassRoles
WARNING: Concept will only be mergable: class alibabaeval.domain.Outer



Generated triples:
<http://example.com/inners/inner1> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://example.com/innerType> .
<http://example.com/inners/inner1> <http://example.com/innerType/data> "some inner data" .
<http://example.com/outers/outer1> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://example.com/outerType> .
_:node1a8hqu4aqx1 <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://example.com/innerType> .
_:node1a8hqu4aqx1 <http://example.com/innerType/data> "some inner data" .
<http://example.com/outers/outer1> <http://example.com/outerType/innerObject> _:node1a8hqu4aqx1 .
<http://example.com/outers/outer1> <http://example.com/outerType/data> "some outer data" .
```

Comment: This is just a guess (I haven't used Alibaba in a while so I'm rusty), but I think the problem is that the id for `Inner` gets added to the store, but your actual `Inner` POJO does not get updated. You may need to add a line `inner = con.getObject(Inner.class, innerId);` after the `addObject`.

Comment: So it's required to round-trip every object through the persistence layer (to assign an ID to it) and replace nested instances in-place (in order to persist a non-basic object graph)?  I'll give it a try when I go back to work, though I hope there's a less complicated way of doing that.

Comment: Adding `inner = con.getObject(Inner.class, innerId);` and adding *that* instance to outer got rid of the b-nodes.  Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear it solved it. I "upgraded" my comment to an answer. Also to adress your performance fear: it shouldn't be too bad as Alibaba does in memory caching of recently accessed objects.

Comment: Performance was only part of it.  The other part was persisting an unmanaged object graph with all the correct IDs (like one unmarshalled from a webservice into POJOs).  I can see at least one way to write the code to do that mechanically, though I was hoping Alibaba could do it for me.  Is there any way to "set" the resource on an unmanaged object so it will be picked up by the single-parameter con.addObject(Object instance)?

Comment: I am not sure. You might have better luck asking this on the Sesame User Group instead, there's more experienced Alibaba users (and its main developer) lurking there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the id for `Inner` gets added to the store, but your actual `Inner` POJO does not get updated. To fix this, simply add a line `inner = con.getObject(Inner.class, innerId);` after the call to `addObject`.

FWIW the additional roundtrip penalty for this is not particularly severe as Alibaba does recent-access object caching - so it will not need to go all the way to the persistence layer for this lookup.

As for how to get the identifying resource back from the object itself: if you make sure your POJO implements the `RDFObject` interface, you can call `getResource` to retrieve the associated id. Your implementation of the `getResource` method can simply return `null`, by the way, as Alibaba will override the implementation in its generated object.

Answer (score 1):

Now that I'm a little more familiar with Alibaba and after taking another read of the documentation, I see a better answer.

Alibaba will use the value returned by RDFObject.getResource() on a detached object.  Here's an implementation of inner that does this:

```
package alibabaeval.domain;

import org.openrdf.annotations.Iri;
import org.openrdf.model.Resource;
import org.openrdf.model.impl.URIImpl;
import org.openrdf.repository.object.ObjectConnection;
import org.openrdf.repository.object.RDFObject;

@Iri("http://example.com/#innerType")
public class Inner implements RDFObject {

    @Iri("http://example.com/innerType/data")
    private String data;

    private Resource detachedId;

    public Inner() {

    }

    @Override
    public ObjectConnection getObjectConnection() {
        // don't really care about this one right now
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Resource getResource() {
        // only run on detached object, is hidden by a proxy on managed objects
        return detachedId;
    }

    public Resource getDetachedId() {
        return detachedId;
    }

    public void setDetachedId(Resource detachedId) {
        this.detachedId = detachedId;
    }

    public void setDetachedId(String detachedId) {
        this.detachedId = new URIImpl(detachedId);
    }

    public void setResource(Resource resource) {
        detachedId = resource;
    }

    public Inner(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

This allows you to do this:

```
    Inner inner = new Inner("some inner data");
    inner.setDetachedId("http://example.com/inners/inner1");

    URI outerId = vf.createURI("http://example.com/outers/outer1");
    Outer outer = new Outer("some outer data");
    outer.setInnerObject(inner);
    con.addObject(outerId, outer);
```

And get these triples:

```
<http://example.com/inners/inner1> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://example.com/#innerType> .
<http://example.com/inners/inner1> <http://example.com/innerType/data> "some inner data" .
<http://example.com/outers/outer1> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://example.com/#outerType> .
<http://example.com/outers/outer1> <http://example.com/outerType/data> "some outer data" .
<http://example.com/outers/outer1> <http://example.com/outerType/innerObject> <http://example.com/inners/inner1> .
```

This technique also works with the single-parameter `ObjectConnection.addObject(Object instance)` method.

This also only works for detached objects.  Instances managed by Alibaba will proxy the RDFObject.getResource() method, so you no longer have control over what it returns.